# how to specify modifiers for a custom directive in VNode context [VueJS 2]

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am trying to add modifier in custom directive that I created inside a VNode but I keep on geeting this error from ts compiler.

```
[tsl] ERROR in /home/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/events.vue.tsx(518,26)
      TS1003: Identifier expected.
```

This is the way I am trying to specify the modifier.

```js
return (
    <div v-customdirective:withLine={{value: 30}}>{ data }</div>
) as VNode;
```

If I remove the modifier there are no errors.

What's the way to do it in a VNode ?

**UPDATE**

I found this link https://vuejs.org/api/render-function.html#withdirectives which talks how to add Custom Directives with VNode and modifiers but its shown as a function.

```js
// <div v-pin:top.animate="200"></div>
const vnode = withDirectives(h('div'), [
  [pin, 200, 'top', { animate: true }]
])
```

Comment: That's how it works. withDirectives is used as a function because it's a HOC. You need to be aware how h() calls correspond to JSX syntax. I.e. it's `withDirectives(<div/>, [...])`